# Mapping the sum of array with reference to main array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here I'm trying to add number of array, but I'm not able to achieve the expected output. I'm able to do total and add them together. But I want add them separately for each object for array.

**Expected output:**

```
[
   {
    "dataModel": 10,
    "itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 0}]
   },
   {
     "dataModel": 20,
     "itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 11}]
   }
]
```

```js
const data = [{
     "dataModel": 10,
    "itemDetails": [{
      "sizeOfBag": 1,
      "numberOfBags": 1,
      "quantityInBag": 1.0
    }]
  },
  {
    "dataModel": 20,
    "itemDetails": [{
        "sizeOfBag": 1,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      },
      {
        "sizeOfBag": 10,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      }
    ],
  }
];

const newData = data.map(f => f.itemDetails);
console.log(newData);

const addData = newData.map(d => d.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.sizeOfBag, 0));
console.log(addData);
```

Comment: Why would you ever want your expected output? You have objects that will only ever have one property and arrays that will only ever have one element; they're as useful as a regular value.

Comment: @Aplet123 Because I need to do sorting for complete object. So I don't want mess up with the structure.  There will be some more parameters in the object. So i want to make a duplicate object with the expected output

Comment: Then just add a `map` at the end that wraps them in the 3 layers of arrays/objects.

Comment: @Aplet123 So i need to create a object with same structure and return it by adding these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `map` two times. You can simply use `d.itemDetails.reduce`. And return object like below to get your desired output.

```
const addData = data.map(d => {
  return {
    dataModel: d.dataModel,
    itemDetails: [{
      totalSizeOfBag: d.itemDetails.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.sizeOfBag, 0)
    }]
  };
});
```

You can test it here.

```js
const data = [{
    "dataModel": 10,
    "itemDetails": [{
      "sizeOfBag": 1,
      "numberOfBags": 1,
      "quantityInBag": 1.0
    }]
  },
  {
    "dataModel": 20,
    "itemDetails": [{
        "sizeOfBag": 1,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      },
      {
        "sizeOfBag": 10,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      }
    ],
  }
];

const addData = data.map(d => {
  return {
    dataModel: d.dataModel,
    itemDetails: [{
      totalSizeOfBag: d.itemDetails.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.sizeOfBag, 0)
    }]
  };
});

console.log(addData);
```